# insert json array into postgres json []

Tags: json, postgresql, insert

How to insert the array ["a","b","c"] into test?

```
create table test( f json [] );
```

I tried

```
insert into test (f) values('{\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"}');
```

but then the escape backslashes are displayed when I select it. **Without escaping it does not work at all. (Token "a" is invalid)**

```
select * from test;

f
----
{"\"a\"","\"b\"","\"c\""}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you just want to insert a json array (`json`) and not an array of json (`json[]`):

```
create table test (f json);
insert into test (f) values(to_json(array['a','b','c']));
select * from test;
       f       
---------------
 ["a","b","c"]
```

In case you want an array of json:

```
create table test (f json[]);
insert into test (f) values
    (array[to_json('a'::text),to_json('b'::text),to_json('c'::text)]);
select * from test;
             f             
---------------------------
 {"\"a\"","\"b\"","\"c\""}
```